# How to set a css class value from variable

Tags: angular

I'm trying to set the color of all 'button' and 'a' tags to a color coming from a variable. Like this, which obviously doesn't work.

```
@Component({
styles: [`    
    a, button {
        color: {{ color_from_variable }};
    }
`]
```

Comment: This is not supported. Use `[class.some-class]="..."` or `[ngClass]="..."` on the element or `@HostBinding('class.some-class') someClass= true;'`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer that is only useful when setting a specific class based on a boolean, I need a color set from configuration

Comment: You can use `ngStyle` as posted in the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This worked for me :

```
export const mainColor = 'blue';

@Component({
  ...
  styles: [`    
    p {
      color: `+mainColor+`;
    }
 `]
})
```

Here is a StackBlitz example I made for this : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vpaarz

Answer (score 0):

You can use [ngStyle](https://angular.io/api/common/NgStyle):

```js
<some-element [ngStyle]="{'font-style': styleExp}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngStyle]="{'max-width.px': widthExp}">...</some-element>

<some-element [ngStyle]="objExp">...</some-element>
```

Comment: ngStyle would be need to be set to every single a and button element ....

Comment: Maybe [ngClass] can help you

Comment: I think ngclass only accepts true or false, but I'll check out the documentation